# How to print binary file output as Base 2 (in bits)?

Tags: python, binary

I have a bin file which contains binary data stored in bytes.

When trying to read them in python, the output is something like this `\xb5D\xbe"jSUk\xe75\x18}@\'%\x89oRqR\xfb\xe9\xe9\`

How can I print file contents as Base 2 binary ?
For example `10000000 01000000 11000000` , etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example reading 8 bytes at a time and formatting them in the way that you describe.

Note that you probably already have system utilities that will do a similar task, for example the `od` program on Unix-like systems.

```python
with open("your_binary_file", "rb") as f:
    while True:
        data = f.read(8)
        if not data:
            break        
        print(" ".join(f"{byte:08b}" for byte in data))
```